# Subsite deletion when removing ability to create subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, site, sub-site

Do existing subsites get deleted when you turn off the ability to create new subsites in SharePoint Online Admin Center?

Or do the existing subsites remain and just the create new subsites link is gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you disable the subsite creation settings from SharePoint Online Admin Center, create new subsites link will gone and users will not be able to create "new" subsites directly through an URL or API.

However, the existing subsites will not be deleted automatically.

---

**Additional**:

Instead of using subsites, Microsoft recommends that you use hub sites. SharePoint hub sites allow you to group similar topics and content together using modern architecture design.

[Plan to create hub sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/create-hub-site) and share [hub site planning guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites) with site owners instead of using subsites.

Comment: Yes, the existing sub sites are remained and just the create new sub sites link is gone.